# Site não está ficando responsivo com Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo

Fiz um site usando bootstrap, mas ele não está ficando responsivo no celular, ele simplesmente aparece como se fosse em um monitor e então com barra de rolagem tanto horizontal, quanto vertical...

http://fbrandaohost.com.br/giulliano_polito/

Esse é o site. 
Pelo navegador do chrome, se vai diminuindo a tela até ficar em um tamanho de um celular, o responsivo fica certinho, o manu se transforma naquele botão de três linhas e tudo mais, até ai tudo bem, mas e por acaso vc clica em F12 e vai no inspecionar elemento e coloca para ver em forma de mobile ou então acessa de um mobile não acontece a adaptação do conteúdo.

Alguém consegue dar um help?
Já troquei os arquivos CSS, conferi os media-queries (@media()) e estão corretos iguais a diversos outros sites que fiz e utilizei o bootstrap tbm!

Comment: o site nem abre aqui também.

Comment: Desculpe renan, eu consertei http://fbrandaohost.com.br/giulliano_polito/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Falta você adicionar no head do site a seguinte linha:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Valeu, de certo, Era isso e tinha passado despercebido!

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa especificar a metatag `viewport`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

#### [template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template)

Comment: Valeu, de certo, Era isso e tinha passado despercebido!